# Are "as of writing" and "at the time of writing" both correct?

Tags: phrases, time, writing

I see that 'at the time of writing' is grammatically correct ([Is 'at the time of writing' correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/199381)).

Is this replaceable with 'as of writing'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the phrase you're looking for is "as of this writing."

Expanding on [the discussion above](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/303064/166329) using Google Ngram Viewer: ["as of this writing" is more common than "as of writing"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as%20of%20writing%2Cat%20the%20time%20of%20writing%2Cas%20of%20this%20writing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) -- though still less than "at the time of writing."

I wanted to call this out, because:

1. I see "as of this writing" frequently in code comments but never "at the time of writing"
2. I was confused to see that "as of writing" was so rare, but it's because of the missing "the"
3. Ngram Viewer suggests "as of writing" is "incorrect" but "as of this writing" is correct (if correct means common)

Comment: OMG this was what I was looking for, as most of my writings are either technical (in the CS field) or a part of code comments! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

I had not encountered "as of writing" before. [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as%20of%20writing%2Cat%20the%20time%20of%20writing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20of%20writing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20time%20of%20writing%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cas%20of%20writing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20time%20of%20writing%3B%2Cc0) shows that it is very rare compared with "at the time of writing". [This site](https://ludwig.guru/s/as+of+writing), which automatically finds examples of phrases in major news sources, has a small number of examples.

Because it is far more common, I think 'as at the time of writing' is the better choice. The shortness of 'as of writing' does not overcome its uncommonness.

Comment: Thank you so much. I learned two things--not only the usage of the phrase, but the tool Google Ngram Viewer.

Comment: Thank you. Google Ngrams isn't perfect, and sometimes you have to be very careful what you search for and how you interpret the results. But generally, when one choice is that much more common, use the more common one unless there is a really good reason not to.